# Removing nginx server_name results in too many redirects

Tags: nginx, wordpress, 301-redirect

I'm trying to test out a new website before replacing the original one, since I don't want to impact users.

I have an existing website at say `example.com` and am working on a separate WordPress site to replace it when ready. To test things during this intermediate stage, that's hosted at `example.net`.

To keep things fast, we're using `nginx` instead of `apache`.

Inside my `nginx.conf`, I've got:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.net www.example.net;
  # etc: location blocks that talk to wordpress and php
}
```

I've got this running on an `EC2` instance, sitting behind a `load-balancer`.

**The Issues**:

If I run `curl -vk load-balancer-dns.com`, it includes: `< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`, and `< Location: http://example.net`

Issue 1) I don't want this to create `301` to `example.net`, because sometime soon I'm going to change this to `example.com` when I'm ready to switch over.

Since the `server_block` mentioned above is the only server block, I assumed it was the default and that I didn't *need* to put in the `server_name` directive.

Issue 2) However, removing `server_name example.net www.example.net` (and restarting `nginx` so changes take effect), I get `Too Many Redirects`.

I can't figure out where the redirects are coming from - there are no `rewrite`, no `permanent` and no `301`s in my `nginx.conf`.

Not trying to ask 2 questions at once, but I feel like solving one will help solve the other, and also trying to avoid an XY issue. Also, not sure if WordPress is relevant.

Comment: Try running the same `curl` command.

Comment: The redirects most likely come from the load balancer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Running the same `curl` command on what? If I run `curl -vk load-balancer-dns.com` I get the redirect; if I run `curl example.net`, it returns the page correctly.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - Shouldn't the `load-balancer` just be forwarding traffic to the instance, which then should handle serving the webpage in the default server block? The `load-balancer` shouldn't need to know anything about the `domain name` I'm actually trying to visit, should it? I could set `hello.world` in my `/etc/hosts` and point it at the `load-balancer`, and I would expect the page to load correctly, without redirecting. That's what happens with other sites, at least.

Comment: The redirects could also come from the CMS. For example, WordPress has the site URL in configuration, and it can do a redirect to that domain if the current HTTP Host header doesn't match the requested host.